# Connecting to clients server using TLSSocket using flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to connect to client server using `TLS` Socket connection.
This works fine when I am directly accessing it, i.e through IDE but it gives error if I try accessing it through the browser.

Error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2010: Local-with-filesystem SWF files are not permitted to use sockets.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add compiler option `use-network=true`. You can either load local files or use network, so choose your side.